# How to create function for disable all element with button tag after 1 second in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, button, delay

Maybe it'll looks like this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
function disBtn(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {    
                buttons[i].style.display = 'none';    
            }
        }           
, 1000);    
}
```

Could anyone please give me a simple solution so then when I call disBtn() function all button tag in current page is disabled after 1 second delay?

Comment: Because after a second the loop is executed which is hiding all the buttons... you need to create a loop and create multiple time outs with different delays

Comment: I think it works as you posted it no?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/auu8beku/2/

Comment: What happened when you ran the code you posted? And are you trying to *disable* the buttons (as per your description) or *hide* them (as per your code)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/auu8beku/3/

Comment: AmmarHasan, I want use the code without jquery.  ArunPJohny, thanks for your replay. nnnnnn and BillyMoon, the code that I posted is works for hiding and yes now I want to change that to disable. Then I find yangguang's answer is what I need. Thx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
function disBtn(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {    
                buttons[i].setAttribute('disabled',true);    
            }
        }           
, 1000);    
}

disBtn();
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/giyalefiki/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: .setAttribute()? Why not buttons[i].disabled = true?

Comment: @nnnnnn, yes, it's ok

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery

```
function disBtn(){
   setTimeout(function () { $('button').prop('disabled', true); }, 1000);
}
```

Without jQuery

```js
function disBtn() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("button")).forEach(function(btn) {
      btn.disabled = true;
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName() doesn't return an array, so calling forEach() directly will give an error.